# WAMP: phpmyadmin suddenly broke down

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

Hi okay here is the case, i was just recently developing my project when this happend. I tried to update my phpmyadmin manually bevause the one included in the wamp is an old one. After that everything went fine and i continued my work. Then all when i try to convert a password to md5 in phpmyadmin, an error appeared saying something about missing PMA etc. Then i tried to revert to my old version of phpmyadmin when when i try to open it in wamp this message appeared.

> Fatal error: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a
>   property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class
>   definition "PMA\libraries\ThemeManager" of the object you
>   are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called
>   or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in
>   C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\libraries\common.inc.php on line 683

i tried all kinds of stuff to fix this and the internet does not seem to have this type of problem :( Can anyone please tell me what to do? i've tried reinstalling chrome and wamp but still this happend and i can't even access my files in www folder anymore :( please help me.

Comment: On the main page, what phpMyAdmin version does it say you're using?

Comment: This might be because of a failed upgrade or old files in the cache; try removing the entire old folder and copying the new one again, then clear your browser cache and remove any phpMyAdmin cookies (which start with "pma").

Comment: It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing today myself after updating to 4.6.0, what I did to solve the problem was delete the contents of the phpmyadmin directory except for the config file (config.inc.php in the root). Once that was done I re uploaded 4.5.4 which can be obtained from here https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/tree/MAINT_4_5_4 just click download zip in the top right & this is their official repo by the way.