# PhpMyAdmin can't encrypt to MD5

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

[image]

Hey guys,

I was wondering why is this happening? That's all I got.
To insert or even to update, it will have that error. But when I used SQL and type :

> UPDATE `htb_user` SET `password` = MD5('admin12345') WHERE `htb_user`.`idUser` = 1

Funny enough, it works. So why is this happening to only me?
I'm using it from xampp from https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html Version 7.3.2-2

Comment: MD5 is not a safe hashing algorithm to use to protect passwords.  It has been too weak to use for this purpose for years.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the info. But as of right now, I'm still a beginner and this is required in my Final Year Project. Thus, I need to solve this A.S.A.P.

Comment: I found the reason

basically follow this post [WAMP: phpmyadmin suddenly broke down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247236/wamp-phpmyadmin-suddenly-broke-down?r=SearchResults)

TL;DR: the only reason it failed is because the char limit was there, that's it